# How to integrate Magento into Wordpress?

Tags: magento-1.7, wordpress, integrate

I want to integrate Magento to a wordpress site. I tried with this plugin. http://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/ But after installation nothing changed.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wordpress is a CMS, while Magento is a giant MVC framework. You are asking to integrate Magento into Wordpress. You'll never get it. Magento is not something plug-n-play which you can connect with wordpress and you will start selling. It could be used with Drupal (again bad idea) but not with Wordpress.

My suggestion is to go for some wordpress e-commerce plugin, like WP e-Commerce. Or as @yarma said, you should install Magento and then integrate Wordpress using FishPig's extension which is quite popular.

If you still want to stick with your question, then I think this question should be asked at [Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 5):

I can advice this one and it is very popular extension:
http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/

Comment: Yes maybe it's better to turn this around!

Comment: @yarma : Thanks for the response. But my question is opposite what you have provided