# Magento 2 - How to integrate Wordpress into Magento 2 system

Tags: magento2, wordpress, integrate

In Magento 2, how to integrate Wordpress? And create new menu for the posts.
I found this solution ([here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10845/how-to-integrate-magento-into-wordpress) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52092/how-to-integrate-wordpress-post-in-magento)) for magento1.x. Please show me step by step.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can download the code from Github [link](https://github.com/bentideswell/magento2-wordpress-integration/blob/master/registration.php)

Create a folder like your Magento 2 root /app/code/FishPig/WordPress and use the copy you downloaded.

**Installation detail**

This installation guide will use http://www.example.com as your Magento URL and http://www.example.com/blog/ as your integrated blog URL. You will need to substitute in your own domain blog route (eg. /blog/).

Feel free to post a question if you struck.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I have also installed the same plugin but having an issue while custom page display with shortcodes. Please see more details at: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192644/magento-2-fishpig-wordpress-integration Could you please help on it?

Answer (score 0):

***You can use FishPig Module to integrate WordPress in Magento 2***

First, install WordPress in to your Magento 2 root directory.

Then Download and extract the [FishPig Module][1]. You will get magento2-wordpress-integration-master. Upload this folder in your Magento store at app/code/FishPig and rename it to WordPress.

Now run these commands in Magento 2 root diectory:

```
php bin/magento module:enable FishPig_WordPress
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now just need to do some configuration on WordPress.